# How to make the user to get sqlite db when he installs my Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.forms, installation, prerequisites

1. I installed a SQLite db on my device (Android).
2. I wrote a Xamarin.Forms application which uses that SQLite db.

The question:
When I upload my app to the market, how will a new user get the SQLite db? does he need to install SQLite db **before** he install my app?

Some of the tables in that db should be semi filled and some should be empty.

Comment: if you need prepopulated db then It should be bundled with your app and installed on 1st use

Comment: The database should be bundled or created from the app. There is plenty of tutorial online on how to do that

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ship a prepopulated database, you must bundle the database with your app. There is no need to install any database server. SQLite is serverless and works inside your app.
You can use [GreenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/) or [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) to interact with your database easier.

You can also host your database in a remote server and fetch the data with RestApi.